# How do I get the wandering magician?

Tags: snoopys-street-fair

I downloaded the latest update, and now the loading page mentions the "new wandering magician" I can apparently have at my Street Fair.

I looked at the booths, all of Snoopy and Charlie Brown's friends, and the landscape items, and I can't seem to see the magician anywhere.

I would really love to have a magician at my fair! How can I make this happen?

Comment: You sure play some interesting games, @AshleyNunn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a sale item. They mention it in the update description. I was looking everywhere too.

Comment: Oh, nifty. I missed that! Gotta save my Snoopy Dollars for that, then! :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be up for sale soon, at this stage as in today. Just the air baloon, candy floss display, and the baloon stand up for sale.

Comment: It was actually up for sale a while ago, too. :) I got it then.